# Getting out of a gang

Tags: society, government, medieval, secret-society

The setting is a high-fantasy medieval metropolis. This is for a Dungeons and Dragons background.

I have a character that was adopted into an orphanage at a young age. Unfortunately, the head of the orphanage raises the kids to be criminals, training them in how to evade the law, and how to sneak around. Once they come of a certain age, the guardian sells the kids to various criminal organizations based on their talent. This character has been part of a certain syndicate for a while now, about 8 years. (he's 23, never new his parents) He wants out of the gang and wants to stop being a criminal, just wants a normal life.

In this world, magic is highly restricted and supervised. All casters must be registered, or else suffer legal action. Unregistered casters are often imprisoned, questioned, and occasionally (if they are assumed dangerous) executed. This character was trained in magic by the syndicate so he is unregistered. This means that he cannot turn to legal aid since they will detect unregistered magic, and imprison him. Since he is a magic user, the gang doesn't want to let him go.

This is the background that one of my players wants to use, so I told him I'd make it work.

So here's my question: How would someone cut ties with a gang, in an urban medieval setting, without using official legal aid? The gang doesn't want to let him go, but has his name, and face on record, and would rather see him dead than out.

Comment: Hello *Jarid Summers*, and welcome to Worldbuilding.  This seems like an interesting question, but perhaps you could explain the magical abilities of the character, as well as the resources of the gang, a little more fully.  Please take our [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site.   Have a nice day!

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! I see Gryphon already pointed you to our [tour] and [help], but you may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) (both of which require 5 rep to post on) useful. Have fun!

Comment: Ask this question in: https://rpg.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Gryphon, Thanks for asking for clarification. The Magical abilities of the character are limited. He is currently undergoing training as a hit man, but has yet to unlock significant powers. At most, he can deliver near-fatal shocks to those he makes physical contact with, and perform minor illusions, light-shows, and kinetic manipulations. Nothing more than Gandalf used in the LotR movies.

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper I don't think it'll be a good place. Looks too opinion based and open ended. Unless, of course, it is a published city and published syndicate.

Comment: As for the resources of the gang, I'd need to do a bit more brainstorming on them for specifics. However, I do know that that city they're currently in is founded religiously. Due to some in-depth circumstances, the streets are constantly patrolled by not only standard guards, but freelance paladins and clerics, looking to aid the weak and poor, and uphold the law when the guards cannot. Because of this, organized crime syndicates take extra precautions to ensure their secrecy and security. The gang would likely have extremely safe hide-outs, moles, and sentinels. quality over quantity.

Comment: @Molot If rpg.stackexchange.com is not a good place, then where would you suggest I take questions such as this? And no, it is not a published city or syndicate

Comment: @Jarid Summers, Dungeons and dragons questions should be asked in rpg.stackexchange. You may run into the mentioned problem of the question being opinion based, as Molot suggests. However this is going to be a problem on ALL stackexchanges.

Comment: @JaridSummers As noted above - open ended and opinion based questions are not good fit on any Stack Exchange site. That's just the wait is.

Comment: @Tyler S. Loeper Thanks for your advice. I'll keep this in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 2):

A *gang* has rules and traditions, not laws. So he could try to make a **deal** with his former co-conspirators to be allowed to "retire" more or less permanently.

- Perhaps he could "buy" himself out of service by paying what a different gang would have to pay for his services now, or what the gang had originally paid plus interest.
- He would have to give credible assurances that secrets will remain secret.
- Or he could get himself enough of a position in the gang that he can blackmail them into letting him go. Say he was the the accountant, and he has a hidden copy of the accounts. Turning them over to the government would be suicidal, but he has arranged for the documents to be delivered if he is dead or detained.
- He could stay formally part of the gang, and convince them that it is a good investment of the gang's assets (including him) to let him live a normal live. Some sort of money laundering scheme, with him managing a seemingly legitimate business for the gang. Or operating an inn that serves as a safe house for senior gang members if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**Have someone else do it**

You say, the main character can't run to the medieval police because main char would get arrested. Knowledge is power and grows like a flower. Use it! There has to be someone that dislikes the gang. The gang has probably committed some scummy actions and irritated a few locals.

Your main character should exploit that by collecting as much gang info as possible. Then you tell a third party (someone that was screwed over by the gang lets call him Tom) that the gang needs to go down. Collect proof, draw maps of the gangs stronghold, find out new heists that the gang will pull. Feed that info to Tom and let Tom talk to the authorities.

This works even better if Tom is a pillar of the community or has a shop in town. Tom has motivation to report the gangs for their crimes, but no motivation to report the crimes of the main char. Your main character could even build rapport with Tom and maybe make a legitimate career for himself.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your character is a caster my best answer would probably be magic!

- if your character is a wild magic sorcerer for example (or just has an accident in training) then a wild magic surge kills the rest of the gang, or makes them forget about him.
- your character kills the other gang members brutally with toll the dead or burning hands while they sleep. a bit cruel but it could give your character internal conflict which they
- hit them with a sleep spell and use that minute of time to get a head start, steal their cash buy a fast horse and run as far as possible

there are of course other, less magic based, ways of getting out of a gang.

- unofficial aid, perhaps a rival gang needs a caster or an adventuring party (hint hint whichever party you are playing with) decides they need an caster outside of offical channels and agrees to protect him from the gang.
- use blackmail to convince the gang that you're more trouble than you're worth.
- fake your own death or capture on a job then grow a beard, wear a robe all the time change your name to staggath thunderjohn.